# How do I pass arguments?

Tags: pandas, parameters, arguments, response, aliexpress

This is part of my code:

```
req = api.AliexpressSolutionBatchProductInventoryUpdateRequest(url, port)
req.set_app_info(appinfo(appkey, secret))
req.multiple_sku_update_list = {'sku_code': row['model'], 'inventory': int(row['stock'])}
req.mutiple_product_update_list = {'product_id': row['product_id']}

sessionkey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

resp = req.getResponse(sessionkey)
print(resp)
```

when i use it like this i get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GOD\Desktop\Новая папка (2)\test.py", line 31, in <module>
    resp = req.getResponse(sessionkey)
  File "C:\Users\GOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aliexpress\api\base.py", line 300, in getResponse
    raise error
aliexpress.api.base.TopException: errorcode=40 message=Missing required arguments:mutiple_product_update_list.multiple_sku_update_list subcode=None submsg=None application_host=11.131.48.59 service_host=top011131048059.na62
```

https://developer.alibaba.com/docs/api.htm?spm=a219a.7395905.0.0.2d1075fedZYJML&apiId=45135 - official manual
Im trying update stocks, please help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This changes helps:

```
req.mutiple_product_update_list = {"product_id": row['product_id'], "multiple_sku_update_list": [
                {"sku_code": str(inf), "inventory": int(row['stock'])}]}
```